# Date-time conversion fails for valid string

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime

I have simple one line code

```
var startYearString = DateTime.Parse("03/21/2014").Year;
```

I expect this to work, But it throws an error like this

```
System.FormatException was unhandled by user code
HResult=-2146233033
Message=String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.
Source=mscorlib
StackTrace:
    at System.DateTime.Parse(String s)
    at ConnectBLL.usercontrols.users.UserProfile.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
    at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
    at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
    at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
    at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
    at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
    at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
InnerException:
```

I have no idea what went wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use [`DateTime.ParseExact()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) if you already know the Date Format.

Try This:

```
 var startYearString = DateTime.ParseExact("03/21/2014","MM/dd/yyyy",
                                  CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).Year;
```

**Explanation:**

[`yyyy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) -  **Year** in 4 digits
[`MM`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)   -  **Month**  in two digits
[`dd`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)   -  **Date** in two digits

[`hh`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)   -  **Hours** in two digits.
[`mm`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)   -  **Minutes** in two digits.
[`ss`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)   -  **Seconds**  in two digits.

[`fff`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)  -  **Milliseconds**
[`tt`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)   -  **AM** or **PM**.

See this for more information : [DateTime custom formats](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
var provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
var dateString = "03/21/2014";
var format = "d";
var output = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, format, provider);
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your culture is set to the type you are parsing.

```
DateTime.Parse("01/23/2014", new CultureInfo("en-US")); // happy
DateTime.Parse("01/23/2014", new CultureInfo("en-GB")); // sad
DateTime.Parse("23/01/2014", new CultureInfo("en-GB")); // happy
```